# Зависает storyboard при открытии проекта

Tags: xcode

На протяжении 10 дней спокойно кодил в Xcodе. Но после каких-то действий перестал открываться Main.storyboard (бесконечная загрузка и съедается 99% ЦП). При этом Launchscreen загружается спокойно. После перезапуска Xcode есть несколько секунд чтобы открыть какой-либо другой файл. Simulator также работает некорректно, после запуска приложения зависает и не дает производить какие либо действия в приложении (Само приложение можно закрыть и побегать по телефону).

Как можно исправить?

Comment: для этого и всегда нужно иметь систему контроля версий, обычно это git.
в вашем случае вы откатываетесь на рабочий коммит и продолжаете писать код.

Comment: @FreeGor, в итоге принял решение откатится к нулю ( начать все заново ). Хоть и была проделана большая работа, решил, что будет лучше отказаться от Firebase и использовать MySQL, иначе будет проблематичнее ( для меня ) связывать сайт с приложением.

Comment: используйте git, всегда, притом что это денег не стоит. это одно из первых правил профессиональной разработки.

Comment: Можете добавить проект с проблемным сторибордом для разбора в чем может быть причина? В последних версиях проблемы в основном из-за UITextView